# Django AllAuth Customized Templates Not Being Recognized

Tags: python, django, templates, overriding, django-allauth

I've been having trouble customizing Django-Allauth templates. Might be an issue with my TEMPLATE_DIRS value, or with something I'm unaware of. If I point my TEMPLATE_DIRS to just the "Templates/AllAuth" folder in my project directory, it ignores my customized templates. Right now, it's ignoring my current base.html file and my current signup.html/login.html file even though the report says the error is coming from the correct file/folder. How can I fix this?

```
Unclosed tag 'block'. Looking for one of: endblock
```

My current base template:

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

The error occurs on my signup.html page, which looks like:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

{% load url from future %}
{% load i18n %}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>{% trans "Sign Up" %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "stylesheets/sign-up.css" %}" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <img id="logo" src="{% static "media/mobile-logo.gif" %}" />
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="omni-box">
            <p>Create Your My_APP Account</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sign-up-form">
            <form id="sign-up" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Up!" />
            </form>
            <h3>OR</h3>
            <p class="facebook"><img class="social-button" src="{% static "media/facebook.png" %}" />Connect With Facebook</p>
            <p class="twitter"><img class="social-button" src="{% static "media/twitter.png" %} />Connect With Twitter</p>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Template Settings:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates','allauth'))
```

And in my templates/allauth/account folder, I have all of the template files that I have customized. That folderl ies in my project directory.

Answer (score 6):

Might be a little late, but I solved this problem by changing the order of apps in settings.py.  You have to put allauth AFTER the app in which your templates reside.

Comment: Many years later, this helped me resolve my issue. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should place your template files under `templates/account` not under `templates/allauth/account`.

Comment: This didn't work for me; still unclear what does work.